Is there a function on a ERC721 Smart Contract that I can fix this issue with?
I have been having an issue for a month with my smart contract. It isn't allowing any of my community members to list or sweep any NFTs from this collection on any marketplaces at all.
It takes their gas money and will not list, and for sweeping it takes their gas money, returns their funds and doesn’t give them the NFTs they are trying to buy. Does this have anything to do with the function SetApprovalForAll?
When I dug deeper into their transactions I saw that the tx said “one or two errors occurred. Execution reverted”
https://etherscan.io/address/0xb56011fbfdafe460b905a40a4845a49c94712272#events
Has anyone ever heard of this happening before?
I tried it for myself also just to see if this would happen and in fact this is what happened This was on Blur marketplace i tried buying 4 NFTs from my collection that were listed on the secondary market and the same thing happened. Execution reverted
